# MVC for dummies: why does controller have to send anything to views?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, design-patterns, frameworks

If I get this right than function of the Controller is processing POST data and technically making changes to the state of the application (e.g. DB) via Model.

As far as I understand, View also gets data from the Model.

So this is how I understand the workflow:

Client request --> `App Front Controller` --> (if method = POST --> `Controller`) --> `View` --> back to Client

Here `Model` is used by `Controller` to read and write data and by `View` to read data.

So controller is not used every time the page is loaded, in fact, only when app data is added/updated. Most of the times Controller is bypassed.

Thus, how come almost every resource about MVC is talking about Controller sending data to views?

I am trying to write an app using MVC-like pattern. So in my app views always get data for the page from the Model. When Model is updated, I add specific model update time to Memcache. At runtime each View looks up last update time(s) of related model(s) and last time cache for this view was generated. If model was updated before cache was saved, view reads cache, otherwise re-renders based on updated model.

Comment: This can be a confusing subject because MVC as applied to the web (stateless) is different than as was described for use in SmallTalk (desktop application).

Comment: [I think I know why you're stuck. You're stuck because MVC as it was originally conceived about twenty years ago doesn't actually work on the web. Every MVC web framework you've come across is actually a kludge, a hack. They are MVC frameworks because that's the name that people have chosen to use, but it's definitely not MVC.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549857/simple-php-mvc-framework/1549970#1549970)

Comment: So what's more relevant on the Web than old school MVC? I am really interested in knowing before I get too far in the project and changing pattern would become too difficult.

Comment: Folks still call it MVC even though it is different than the original. If you want to get technical, you can look at the description of Model 2 or MVC2 which are closer approximations to how MVC is widely used today on the web.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The controller is responsible for presenting views based on the data that is requested. It's there so neither the model nor the view need to know about the request. Yes, the view gets data from the model, but not always directly; the controller may have to make some decisions as well depending on the request.

It's something like having waiters in a restaurant so they can take orders from and serve dishes to customers. It's not the chefs who bring out the meals after preparing them; it's the waiters. It's not the customers who go to the kitchen asking for meals; it's the waiters who take their orders then let the chefs know what to prepare for whom. In the same way, the controller is there to handle client requests, whatever their nature may be. It's a very rough comparison though, but I hope you get the picture.

Comment: @webbiedave: I don't know... GC?

Comment: That's not MVC. If the model is a dumb one and unaware of its role, it's PMVC at best. If the controller mostly shovels data from the model to the view, then it's actually a presenter, not a controller. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Presenter

Comment: But does this make sense that controllers only act on POST data? And if there is no POST, controllers are not involved?

Comment: @SODA: Not always, in many MVC web frameworks they do handle a variety of request types.

Comment: @BoltClock -- what kind of requests? E.g. pagination?

Comment: @BoltClock -- right, but IMO things like pagination don't really change state of the application, and I thought role of the controller is to update application state.

Comment: @SODA: Well, perhaps mario is right on this (the distinction between presenters/controllers and MVP/MVC). See his comment.

Comment: @SODA: No, mario is not right on this one. He just likes posting interesting links. :] What I'm trying to tell is this: you shouldn't adhere to any specific coding pattern. These things are hypothetical, the definitions are watery, and hardly anyone does it by the book. "MVC" on the web is a buzzword. "MVP" is a better orientation, but you should really just code the most efficient and readable structure that works for you. Call your controller "Controller" if that helps the overview, and make it organize the bulk of input data, processing logic, and yes POST requests.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misinterpreted your question: The problem is with the view accessing the model directly. That's not supposed to happen as it defeats the reason for the MVC pattern. The view shouldn't know anything about the model itself, so the model can be exchanged for something else - the controller should supply the data (at most times it a flattened or projected way) to the view.

If I did: The controller is never bypassed. Just because it doesn't do anything with the data, doesn't mean it isn't needed - it provides a layer of abstraction between model and view. The point is to be able to exchange the model without having to adjust the view.

Comment: See what I wrote to Brettski. If controller is never bypassed than both controller and view have to be in sync as far as data views need. At the other hand, if view does not need controller to generate output, you don't have to worry about controller not providing necessary data.

Comment: The view transmits changes to the controller which acts accordingly and provides the needed data back to the view. Ideally, the view shouldn't hold data its own and only use the data provided by the controller.

Answer (score 1):

The controller is never bypassed as it is required to instruct which views are shown and what data (if any) is used in those views.  Each get or post request to an MVC site uses the controller to control what is shown or collected to/from the client.

At its core MVC is used to separate concerns.  The model works with the data, the views handle presentation and the controller provides the logic between the two.

Comment: Thanks. Question though. Basically if Controller passes data to Views, than Controller MUST know what data is required by Views. And if you change views to use other data, you must update controller accordingly to provide new data? This does not make sense. Extra work and more room for error.

Comment: The controller doesn't necessarily know. In fact it should not know. It just acts as a bridge. You're the one who's supposed to pass the correct Model (or data) to the View. Once you got that, you instruct the controller to fetch the View for you. For a single and simple project, this might be a lot of work. But real projects aren't made from single pages. Usually you have lots of code and lots of programmers. MVC is a good way to separate the concerns and tasks. And debug code. More work now, less pain later.

Comment: You could still proceed with the old way- not using MVC. But in case you need to change the view, you will have to modify not only your data handlers but also the processing logic. In fact by removing the term MVC, it's even hard to communicate these terms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a person that learn faster by getter hands dirty with codes or looking to something visual , like me ....

I will suggest you to follow the tutorial in [railsforzombies.org](http://railsforzombies.org) . It pretty much explain all the basic using rails , including MVC. In the tutorial , It mention that if you put all those logic in view , It will be messy. The code will sux a little bit because the guys that want to use your code will be confused with codes. By putting all the logic in controller and output it in view. It will be very clear for the person that look into your codes.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: The architecture digram will help you dive deeper into the way rails requests are processed.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Controller uses Model, and passes proccessed data to View. View shouldn't see Model. Main goal is -  to keep View separately from Model!

Answer (score 0):

> MVC for dummies: why does controller
>   have to send anything to views?

This is the main point of MVC: to create loose coupling by separating and distinguishing the application's concerns. You have the View, Model, and Controller doing specific tasks.

Why the need for separation because it's hard to debug and fix a one gigantic godzilla app. Imagine fixing a car made from stone. There are no bolts. Everything is chiseled from a big rock. How hard is fixing that if you just want to change the wheels. You will need to chisel out the rock itself.

The main job of the controller is to handle requests and display the appropriate view. That it's job. It's like asking why does the mailman need to send the mail. Because that's his job.

Comment: Thanks. So in practice by "to handle requests and display the appropriate view" you mean parsing URL and loading appropriate view / content id / action? Seems like for GET requests this is the extent of Controller job.

Comment: Each request will be mapped to a particular controller (or controller method). Once the requests has arrived to the controller, you do your processing logic. Maybe call a service to do some stuff with your Model then return a result from this service/Model. Then you select what view should be used to show the result. When you know what you want, then instruct the controller to fetch the view for you and populate this view with the Model result.